# Simple shell program of two parameters (concurrency problem)

Tags: shell, input, concurrency, fork

I am trying to complete an assignment which consists in emulating a simple shell program, that gets only 2 parameters and it runs sequentially or concurrently, depending on the user input.

Alhough, I am having a hard time implementing the concurrent version, because when I type in the input `sleep 1 &` (the ampersan indicates concurrency), the parent  does not wait for the child as expected and keeps iterating, but when it goes to the second iteration of the while loop the `readSplit` function, instead of pausing the program to wait to the user input, it takes the empty `buff` as input.

Nevertheless, if I write `sleep 1` , `ls` or any command that only requires 2 parameters it works fine.

Some clarifications:

-`readSplit` just gets the input of the user. It works like the read() function, but it stops reading when it arrives to the separation character. (I know there is a better function that does the same, but this code was provided by the course).

```
int readSplit( int fin, char* buff, char* s, int maxlen ) {
   int i = 0;
   int oneread = 1;
   char c = *s+1;
   while(c != *s && c != '\n' && oneread == 1 && i < maxlen) {
       oneread = read( fin, &c, 1);
       if(c != *s && c != '\n' && oneread == 1) {
              buff[i] = c;
           i++;
       }
   }
   if(c=='\n') *s = c;
   if(i < maxlen) buff[i] = '\0';
   return i;
}
```

-`startTimer` and `endTimer` can be ignored, they are just measuring the execution time.

MAIN code:

```
#include <sys/types.h> /* pid_t */
#include <sys/wait.h>  /* waitpid */
#include <sys/types.h> /* pid_t */
#include <sys/wait.h>  /* waitpid */
#include <stdio.h>     /* printf, perror */
#include <stdlib.h>    /* exit */
#include <unistd.h>    /* _exit, fork */
#include <string.h>
#include "myutils.h"

int main(void) {
   int ret;
   int status;
   char buff[80];
   char buff_aux[80];
   char ampersan[1];
   long timer;
   int continueloop = 1;

while (continueloop == 1) {

    char s = ' '; //Separator
    /*Cleaning the information in each loop*/


    memset(buff, 0, sizeof (buff));
    memset(buff_aux, 0, sizeof (buff_aux));
    memset(ampersan, 0, sizeof (ampersan));
    write(1, ">", 1);
    /*Reading user input*/

        readSplit(0, buff, &s, 80);
        printf("%s its my buff string\n", buff);

    if (strcmp(buff, "exit") == 0)break; //If the user wants to exit


    /*If the user has one more parameter we read it and put it in the buff_aux*/
    if (s == ' ' ) {
        if (readSplit(0, buff_aux, &s, 80) == 0)
            exit(1);
    }
    printf("%s is my buff_aux string\n", buff_aux);

    if (s == ' ' ) {
        readSplit(0, ampersan, &s, 1);
        printf("%c is the letter read by ampersan\n", ampersan[0]);

    }
    startTimer();
    /*Creating child*/
    ret = fork();
    printf("ret %d\n", ret);
    printf("im checking if it is a child\n");
    if (ret == 0) {
        printf("im a child\n");
        if (buff[0] == 0) {
            printf("Son: shell program does not exist\n");
            exit(255);
        } else if (buff_aux[0] == 0 || buff_aux[0] == '&') {
            printf("Im about to execute 1\n");
            execlp(buff, buff, NULL);
            exit(2);
        } else {
            printf("Im about to execute 2\n");
            execlp(buff, buff, buff_aux, NULL);
            exit(2);

        }
    }
    if (ampersan[0] != '&') {
        wait(NULL);
        timer = endTimer();
        printf("The process finished and lasted ... %li miliseconds\n", timer);
    }


}
/*waiting to children to finish*/
while (wait(NULL) > 0);
timer=endTimer();

printf("Father waited for son\n");
if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
    status = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    if (status > 0) printf("Father: shell program does not exist\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you input `sleep 1 &`, input buffer is `sleep 1 &\n`

first while:

1. call `readSplit(0, buff, &s, 80);`, `buff` is `sleep`, input buffer left `1 &\n`
2. call `readSplit(0, buff_aux, &s, 80)`, `buffer_aux` is `1`, input buffer left `&\n`
3. call `readSplit(0, ampersan, &s, 1);` `ampersan` is `&`, input buffer left `\n`

next while:

input buffer left `\n`

1. call `readSplit(0, buff, &s, 80);`, `buff` is empty, c is `\n`, in child process will call:

```
if (buff[0] == 0) {
   printf("Son: shell program does not exist\n");
   exit(255);
}
```

you should handle `\n` in each `while`